# Error after upgrading Flex SDK: "{ expected "

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

After upgrading the Flex SDK from 3.1 to any newer version of the SDK and trying to compile an existing project, the following error appears in the Problems pane:

`Description: { expected`
`Resource:` *(shows project name, not a specific file)*
`Location: line 15`

Any ideas how to solve this or where to start the bug hunt?

It looks like the problem is in the ...sdks/3.3.0/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc file, but I'm certainly not sure.

Comment: Can you paste in the line which is causing this to fail?

Comment: Is this with one particular project or all your projects?

Comment: Nik, the problem is that in the Resource column there is only the project name, and no file name. I cannot paste the line because I don't know the file in which it is.

Comment: Quoo, I've tested with just this one project for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing halo.swc from libraries. Copying halo.swc to the project was suggested by an online tutorial (which I cannot find right now).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen (among others). Never got to the bottom of it. In the end I migrated my code files to a new project. There are some pretty nasty bugs in FlexBuilder, especially when working on 64bit windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a clean on the project? You didn't mention this but I assume that the project compiles fine under 3.1? If you create a new project does it compile cleanly (if not, it may mean that you have a bad download of the SDK and need to get a new copy.)

Comment: The project compiles fine under 3.1, UNLESS I try to trick it into being Flash 10 compatible by adding the playerglobal.swc to libs. I did do a clean on the project, but that didn't help. This same problem is happening on two machines, and with all SDKs targeting Flash 10 (Gumbo included).
We will try copying the source code to a new project folder tomorrow and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure you need any trickery to compile for v10 (i.e. subbing playerglobal.swc). Somewhere in the project properties (not at my machine at the moment, but it's on the HTML wrapper page) you simply set the min version to 10.